# ADF Change color of inputfile button

Tags: button, file-io, oracle-adf

I would like to  change the colour of the inputfile button. My other buttons have background black and text white when they are active and background white and text black on hover. I do this with inputfile button but in Pseudo-Elements I am not meeting this property.

I saw [this](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E18745_01/devguide/fileUpload.html) page but I don't understand very well how I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
af|inputFile::content {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Not result Sidney. the button don't change.